# REST HTTP status code for "success, and thus you no longer have access"

Tags: http, rest, http-status-codes

My RESTful service includes a resource representing an item ACL.  To update this ACL, a client does a `PUT` request with the new ACL as its entity.  On success, the `PUT` response entity contains the sanitized, canonical version of the new ACL.

In most cases, the HTTP response status code is fairly obvious.  `200` on success, `403` if the user isn't permitted to edit the ACL, `400` if the new ACL is malformed, `404` if they try to set an ACL on a nonexistent item, `412` if the `If-Match` header doesn't match, and the like.

There is one case, however, where the correct HTTP status code isn't obvious.  What if the authenticated user uses `PUT` to remove themselves from the ACL?  We need to indicate that the request has succeeded but that they no longer have access to the resource.

I've considered returning `200` with the new ACL in the `PUT` entity, but this lacks any indication that they no longer have the ability to `GET` the resource.  I've considered directly returning `403`, but this doesn't indicate that the `PUT` was successful.  I've considered returning `303` with the `Location` pointing back to the same resource (where a subsequent `GET` will give a `403`), but this seems like a misuse of `303` given that the resource hasn't moved.

So what's the right REST HTTP status code for "success, and thus you no longer have access"?

Comment: Have any of these answers been helpful?

Comment: @Kylar: Yes, several. Difficult to pick the right one to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

200 is the appropriate response, because it indicates success (as any 2xx code implies). You may distinguish the user's lack of permission in the response (or, if you don't wish to, 204 is fine). Status codes make no contract that future requests will return the same code: a 200 response to the PUT does not mean a subsequent GET can't return 403. In general, servers should never try to tell clients what will happen if they issue a particular request. HTTP clients should almost always leap before they look and be prepared to handle almost any response code.

You should read the [updated description of the PUT method in httpbis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-23#section-4.3.4); it discusses not only the use of 200/204 but indicates on a careful reading that returning a transformed representation in immediate response to the PUT is not appropriate; instead, use an ETag or Last-Modified header to indicate whether the entity the client sent was transformed or not. If it was, the client should issue a subsequent GET rather than expecting the new representation to be sent in response to the PUT, if for no other reason than to update any caches along the way (because the response to a PUT is not cacheable). [Section 6.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-23#section-6.3.1) agrees: the response to a PUT should represent the status of the action, not the resource itself. Note also that, for a new ACL, you MUST return 201, not 200.

Comment: "An origin server MUST NOT send a validator header field (Section 7.2), such as an ETag or Last-Modified field, in a successful response to PUT unless the request's representation data was saved without any transformation applied to the body (i.e., the resource's new representation data is identical to the representation data received in the PUT request) and the validator field value reflects the new representation." In other words, return an `ETag` only if the `PUT` entity exactly matches that which would be returned from a subsequent `GET`?

Comment: I have found neither suggestion nor prohibition to return the representation of a resource in the response to PUT request. Otherwise, the answer is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two semantic ideas, and trying to combine them into a single response code.

The first: That you successfully created an ACL at the location that you were attempting to. The correct semantic response (in either a RESTful or non-RESTful scenario) is a **201 Created**. From the RFC: "The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created."

The second: That the user who executed the PUT does not have access to this resource any more. This is a transient idea - what if the ACL is updated, or something changes before the next request? The idea that a user does not have access to a resource of any kind (and this includes an ACL resource) *only matters for the scope of that request.* Before the next request is executed, something could change. On a single request where a user does not have access to something you should return a **403 Forbidden**.

Your PUT method should return a 201. If the client is worried about whether it has access any more, it should make a subsequent request to determine it's status.

Comment: Disagree about 201. Assuming every item has a default ACL, then the PUT correctly returns 200.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at HTTP response code "204 No Content" (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), indicating that the "server has fulfilled the request [to be removed from the ACL] but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation" (here, as a result of the successful removal). Although you're not allowed to return a message body with 204, you can return entity headers indicating changes to the user's access to the resource. I got the idea from Amazon S3 - they return a 204 on a successful DELETE request (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html), which seems to resemble your situation since by removing yourself from an ACL, you've blocked access to that resource in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question :-) This is why I love REST, sometimes it might get you crazy. Reading [w3 http status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) I would choose (this of course is just my humble opinion) one of those:

- 202 Accepted - since this mean "well yes I got your request, I will process it but come back later and see what happens" - and when the user comes back later she'll get a 403(which should be expected behavior)
- 205 Reset Content - "Yep, I understood you want to remove yourself please make a new request, when you come back you'll get 403"

On the other hand (just popped-up in my mind), why should you introduce a separate logic and differentiate that case and not using 200 ? Is this rest going to be used from some client application that has an UI? And the user of the rest should show a pop-up to the end-user "Are you sure you want to remove yourself from the ACL?" well here the case can be handled if your rest returns 200 and just show a pop-up "Are you sure you want to remove user with name  from the ACL?", no need to differentiate the two cases. If this rest will be used for some service-to-service communication(i.e. invoked only from another program) again why should you differentiate the cases here the program wouldn't care which user will be removed from the ACL.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Both of those are quite wrong. 202 is for continuing processing. 205 is to tell the UI to clear a form.

Comment: Well, you're correct, maybe I interpret them wrong. However, I continue to see no point in introducing separate logic and differentiate this situation from the normal case when the user removes another user. This can be handled on UI level if it is so important with appropriate warning message.